# Dynamic loop in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark

I  have a query by which I need to make dataframe using dynamic spark sql
select col1 ,col2 col3 as code
from
table 1
inner join table 2
on a1 = a2
where
condition1 and conditon2
group by
col n
col m
col 3
here col 3 has 6 different value . so I need to loop through one by one for every col 3 value and store all result in single data frame

Please advise on this

I tried with declaring declaring single value , but how to loop through multiple value of column

Comment: please share actual code you tried and input data schemas and sample data along with your expected output schema and sample data.